# What is the difference between using partial and not using partial for tornado.options.define?

Tags: python, web, tornado, higher-order-functions

I see two ways of setting up define in tornado.

```
import tornado.options
def define_web(hidden=False):

    define = partial(tornado.options.define, group='Web', hidden=hidden)
    define('thread', False, type=bool,
        help='threading')
```

and without using partial

```
from tornado.options import options, define

def define_web(hidden=False):
    define('thread', False, type=bool,
        help='threading')
```

So I was wondering what is the difference, and what is advantage of using partials

Answer (score 0):

`partial` lets you specify certain arguments once and use them repeatedly. In your first example, the `thread` option has `group="Web", hidden=hidden`, while in the second example these arguments are not used.